# Lead not connected

Tags: citroen, connector

Does anyone know what this lead is for as it’s not connected to anything in my citroen berlingo.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure on your specific vehicle, but some manufacturers put leads such as that in the engine compartment which are used as test leads. Since the connector is yellow, I'd also have to assume that has something to do with the SRS (air bags). If you aren't seeing any dash lights, either for check engine or SRS, I'm betting there's no issue. I wouldn't know for sure, though, so hopefully someone with some knowledge of Citroen's will have a better idea then I would.

Comment: On the dashboard the airbag light is on. I have looked in the bonnet but can’t see anywhere for it to connect to.

Comment: What is/are the codes?

Comment: Sorry don’t know the codes